# Mantain coordinates with matlab

Tags: matlab, geotiff

I'm doing some operation with some tif images (well, the format is geotiff because it's a tif with coordinates) in Matlab but after doing it, I cannot mantain the coordinates of the images. I've thought about generating a tfw file but I receive errros. The way to reading it and writing is with the imread and imwrite commands.

Does somebody know how can I do it?

thanks!

Comment: With coordinates, do you mean geographical coordinates or pixels? Also how do you read the image?

Comment: Yes, geographical coordinates. I read it on that way:                         for i=1:length(tifFiles)
    
    baseFileName = tifFiles(i).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(dir_entrada, baseFileName);
    imageArray = imread(fullFileName);

Comment: Ok, I think `imread` creates an image and return image data. Try `geotiffread` instead.

Comment: Because of the format, it's not possible to do that (it's an uint16 and then, is not allowed to geotiffwrite)

Comment: So then you mean that you do not have geotiff format? You explicitely state that it is a geotiff image. Please clarify the question. What format do you have?

Comment: An easy way to clarify what you have would be to show us the output of `imfinfo` on one of your files.  `imread`/`imwrite` won't work here but you can set metadata on tif files using LibTiff via MATLAB.